# Strange python 'is' operator in arithmetic

Tags: python

I tried this operation in python interactive mode :

```
>>> (1*1) is 1
True
>>> (377*35) is 13195
False
>>> 377*35
13195
>>> 377*35 is 377*35
False
>>> 1*1 is 1
True
```

Could anybody explain why ' (377*35) is 13195 ' is false?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you use `is` here at all?

Comment: I was doing mental math, just tried to type the answer directly instead of hitting enter. But '==' gets no problem at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A is B` checks that `A` and `B` refer to the same object. It does not check whether `A` equals `B` numerically.

The reason for the different behaviour in your examples is that ints with small values (typically between -1 and 99
inclusive) are "interned" by the interpreter -- whenever a result has such a value,
an existing short int with the same value is returned.

This explains why `is` returns `True` for your examples involving small numbers but not for those involving large numbers.

Comment: The interned range is -5 to +256 inclusive.